# Heteroscedasticity in Data, none in Subset

Tags: heteroscedasticity, consistency, subset

This might seem like a trvial questions to some but sadly not me.

My dataset has heteroscedasticity and therefore I use a heteroscedasticity consistent standard error estimator (I use the RLM macro by Andrew Hayes in SPSS) for my analysis.

Now I also look at a subset of my data (59 datapoints, complet set 950 datapoints). In this subset there is no heteroscedasticity. Should I still, to stay consistent, use hcse for my analysis of this subset or not?

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: What sort of analysis do you want to do of the subset?  Do you want to draw inferences from the subset about a larger population?

Comment: No I don't want to draw inferences about a larger population. It is more kind of a comparison. The full dataset is hockey games played over a couple of seasons and the subset is games with an injury. And I would compare the results, to see the influence of an injury.